# How to determine on which Root Hub Port is connected a usb device after an Enable Slot Command with the Intel's xHC?

Tags: usb, x86-64, interrupt, osdev, hci

I am writing a small driver for the Intel's xHC in a small hobby OS I boot with UEFI.

After I reset all Root Hub Ports, I get 2 Port Status Change Events which is because I asked QEMU to emulate a usb keyboard and a usb mouse in the command line. One Port Status Change Event for each device seems fair. After this, I follow the initialization steps for a USB device. As stated in the xHCI spec:

> After the port successfully reaches the Enabled state, system software shall obtain a Device Slot for the newly attached device using an Enable Slot Command, as described in section 4.3.2.

I thus send an Enable Slot Command to each Root Hub Port for which there was a Port Status Change Event. This seems to work because I get 2 Command Completion Events on the Event Ring which both trigger an interrupt. Both of these events are marked with a completion code of 1 which indicates success.

My problem starts here. In the Port Status Change Event is a Port ID field which allows to determine which port triggered the event. In the Command Completion Event, there is none of that. I can link to the Command TRB which triggered the event but the Command TRB doesn't include the Port ID. My problem is that after an Enable Slot Command I need to create an Input Context including a Slot Context which should contain the Root Hub Port number.

I could keep a list of the ports to which I sent an Enable Slot Command but that opens up to race conditions especially once multiprocessing is enabled.

How do I properly get which Root Hub Port triggered the Command Completion Event?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb@vger.kernel.org/msg105361.html), the *Enable Slot* command only gives you an index (ie the Slot ID) in the Device Context Base Address Array. This index is **not** tied to any port, it's just a free entry. You have to initialize it with a pointer to a Device Context structure and fill its Slot Context with *whatever* Port Number and Route String you want. So you can just queue the slots to initialize and dequeue them as the Command Completion Events arrives.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Basically, I get a free Slot ID and then decide what port this free Slot ID is going to be paired with by filling the Device Context structures associated with it.

Comment: I'll check out if it works right now. Maybe post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it's definitively useful as an answer. Let me know if it did work.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom It does work. I am now able to address devices. Not yet getting keyboard input but I'm getting close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has been asked on the linux-usb maillist.
[There, Mathias Nyman, points out that the *Enable Slot* is misleading](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb@vger.kernel.org/msg105361.html) because **it doesn't enable the slot of a specific port** instead the command just returns a free index in the *Device Context Base Address Array*.
This index is the *Slot ID* value.

The programmer has to set the corresponding entry (i.e. `dev_ctx_base_addr[slot_id]`) with a pointer to a *Device Context* structure and fill its *Slot Context* with **whatever** *Port Number* and *Route String* they deem appropriate.
It's important to stress out that there is no a priori relationship between the *Slot ID* and the *Port Number/Route String*.

So you can just have a queue of slots to initialize and dequeue them as the *Command Completion Events* arrive.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Very useful as always.